# doctrine 2 persist object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have object with relation, and want save it, but I have only id and don't want get object from database.

When I persist, I have this error:

> Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given

I think need use DataTransformers? Сan someone tell me how to use it?

Comment: pls post your code where you persist the object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `EntityManager::getReference($entityName, $id)` to get a reference to the related record.

Read the [getReference doc](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L443).